# Custom Arduino powered board (CH340C) Serial Problem

Tags: arduino, serial

[image: Schematic]
[image: USB connector]
[image: PCB]

I made this custom board that contains a complete Arduino Nano on it. I soldered every component with extreme care, and already checked all the connections and they all go according to the designed schematics. However, I seem to have a problem with the serial communication between the computer and the board. I'm almost certain the problem has to do with my CH340C IC, but I have already replaced it 3 times.

This is the problem:

[image: Here we can see the error that I'm having]

I know the Arduino is working because I burned the bootloader and uploaded some example sketches to it through the ICSP pins.

Maybe I have a design flaw?

Comment: Do you have: * Decoupling capacitors on the CH340C? * Good differential pair routing for D+ and D- (maybe it's not so important for low speed USB though)? * Have you double checked the connections on the micro-USB connector?

Comment: Sometimes the connections on the USB are numbered in reverse. Are you getting +5 on VUSB? See [the original](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/Arduino_Nano-Rev3.2-SCH.pdf) Arduino schematic.

Comment: The IC is receiving solid 5V from a on board boost converter. I've check the connections on the USB connector and everything just as described on the schematics. I also use the USB power to charge a battery, and the battery is charging just fine.

Comment: I have a couple capacitor in the output of the boost converter. 4.7uf and 22uf. The routing on D+ and D- is nothing special but at least the PC should recognize the IC.

Comment: So do you have a capacitor each on the 5V and 3.3V lines of the CH340C, nearby to the IC? Actually the [datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/Arduino/Other/CH340DS1.PDF) (translated from Chinese) recommends that when using 5V power, connect the 3.3V pin to a 0.01uF capacitor and do not connect it to power. Apparently it has some internal regulator.

Comment: Your comment seems to be a statement that you do not, in fact, have bypass capacitors.  The capacitors you describe are far too large to serve that purpose - at logic frequencies they are not really capacitors at all.

Comment: Schematics don't always tell the whole story... maybe your footprints are wrong?

Comment: The 3.3V net is not used at all, and it does have an internal regulator, I've measured this 3.3V. But ill adapt a 100nF cap to it and see if it changes anything. Anything else you might think i should do?

Comment: "everything just as described on the schematics" Well, that's usually a given. But are the schematics and footprint mapping to schematic symbols correct?

Comment: Yep, I've measured the 3.3V output of the board and it works. Also the footprint mapping is done automatically by the software and every thing else is working as intended. I added a picture of the PCB

Comment: SOLVED! The problem was the decoupling capacitors, I solder 2 capacitor directly on the 5V and 3.3V pins of the IC and the computer immediately recognized the chip. Ill be sure to not forget them for rev. 2 of this board. Thank you immibis and Chris Stratton! and everyone else that commented :D